# Google API Translation v2 translates more than it should

Tags: java, api, translation

I got a problem which is pretty frustrating... 
The API Translation v2 is doing more than it should !

When I perform a request to translate from Polish to French, it works well, but it also translates the english words in french, and I don't want that.

The request in POST

```
    https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=[key]
```

Body :

```
    {"q":"hello, budowa","target":"fr","format":"html","source":"pl","model":"base"}
```

And the answer of the WS is

```
    {
      "data": {
      "translations": [
          {
              "translatedText": "bonjour, construction",
              "model": "base"
          }
      ]
      }
     }
```

But instead of "bonjour, construction" I'm waiting for "hello, construction"

I found a way to ignore translations with some HTML code but it won't solve the problem in this case.

Do you have any workaround ?